# Adding link to an element in Javascript? (Current method risks "bad javascript?")

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have some element

```
 <span class="CLASSNAME" id="FOO">Barack Obama</span>
```

Referenced by

```
 document.getElementById('FOO')
```

And I want to make it so the text "Barack Obama" is turned into a blue link where the text is the same, but it links to (for example) www.google.com

I've seen this method, but innerHTML is apparently BAD especially since the link I'll be using is a value returned from an ajax call ("potential for bad js"?).

```
 document.getElementById('FOO').innerHTML = desiredText.link(desiredLink);
```

What is the best way to go about this without a huge perfomance hit or potentially "bad js"? Will also be adding mouseover features to said element later on, so if this is worth consideration I figured I'd mention it. No jQuery.

Comment: why are you worried about performance hit on modifying just a single node?

Comment: @mehulmpt Good practice, really. This is a first side project so don't want to pick up bad habits while I learn JS. Also, this will be done 1-100 times every time my script is run. (It's run with sizeable delays, though). Ultimately to not pick up bad habits.

Comment: If you're really worried about the performance of DOM manipulation, wouldn't there be a way to avoid it? Why can't the original HTML contain the anchors?

Comment: @PeterMader I don't have access to the page itself, just running a script on some website. If that's not what you meant, I just didn't understand sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
var el=document.getElementById('FOO');
el.innerHTML="<a href='whitehouse.gov'>"+el.textContent+"</a>";
```

Simply wrap it into a link. Note that html injection is possible. And do not care about performance, were talking about milliseconds...

If you want to prevent html injectin, you may  build it up manually:

```
var el=document.getElementById('FOO');
var a=document.createElement("a");
a.href="whitehouse.hov";
a.textContent=el.textContent;
el.innerHTML="";
el.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. My first thought too

Comment: I like the second, seems clean. Really reluctant to use the first one for the simple reason that the method I found already avoids the hassle with concatenating strings and I think is more or less the same. Regarding the second, does this leave an empty element or (new to JS, not sure how to say this) otherwise? When you set el.innerHTML=""; That isn't a bad practice or anything? Not better to completely replace the entire node with something like parentnode.replacechild(a) or something?

Comment: Totally looking to learn, really appreciate the help. Learning about the differences of all these methods to accomplish this is extremely helpful. Thank you very much, again.

Comment: @Kevin yes then youve got <span><a></a></span> in both cases. i woudlnt remove the span. you would lose custom styling youve applied to it.

Comment: If you start with `<span id="FOO">&lt;script>alert('lolhax');&lt;/script></span>` then your `el.textContent` will *unescape* it when you inject it with `innerHTML`. Prefer the second method, with keeps `textContent` as `textContent`.

Comment: What is the difference between your first solution and Peter's solution? They both seem to create the same structure. Right?

Comment: @Kevin peters solution equals mysecond one. you may just use the first if you removed all < >  from the ajax data... (or you may get html injected)

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

#### Add an `<a>` element as a child of the `<span>` element

Replace the text node ("Barack Obama") with an `<a>` element:

```js
function addAnchor (wrapper, target) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = target;
  a.textContent = wrapper.textContent;
  wrapper.replaceChild(a, wrapper.firstChild);
}
addAnchor(document.getElementById('foo'), 'http://www.google.com');
```

```html
<span id="foo">Barack Obama</span>
```

This will result in the following DOM structure:

```html
<span id="foo">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Barack Obama</a>
</span>
```

#### Replace the `<span>` element with an `<a>` element

Replace the entire `<span>` element with an `<a>` element:

```js
function addAnchor (wrapper, target) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = target;
  a.textContent = wrapper.textContent;
  wrapper.parentNode.replaceChild(a, wrapper);
}
addAnchor(document.getElementById('foo'), 'http://www.google.com');
```

```html
<span id="foo">Barack Obama</span>
```

This will result in the following DOM structure:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Barack Obama</a>
```

Use methods like `createElement`, `appendChild` and `replaceChild` to add element instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the first solution would be the better one if I have the intent to add event handlers for mousover (display a text box on hover)? If so, would it be better to handle the mouseover before or after adding the <a> element? That way it's simpler to identify the element with the selector I already have

Comment: If you have to do some things with the `<span>`, then use the first approach. But it shouldn't matter when you bind the event listener to the `<span>`.

Comment: Note that your first solution will fail if there's more than 1 node inside a `span`, for example: `<span id="foo">Barack <em>The President</em> Obama</span>` will produce unexpected result.

Comment: What is the difference between this and Jonas's solution? They both seem to create the same structure. Right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var changeIntoLink = function(element, href) {
  // Create a link wrapper
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = href;
  
  // Move all nodes from original element to a link
  while (element.childNodes.length) {
    var node = element.childNodes[0];
    link.appendChild(node);
  }
  
  // Insert link into element
  element.appendChild(link);
};

var potus = document.getElementById('potus');
changeIntoLink(potus, 'http://google.com/');
```

```html
<span id="potus">Barack Obama</span>
```